# How to get substr of max value using select statment in php

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to to get sub string from max value searched from database but failed. My string is `AB/LAJ/GER/R4/0210/001` format where 02 is month and 10 is year and last 000 are increment numbers as records are added. I want to select max year and last 000 max number from database and using this command

```
"SELECT substr(max(serial), 16) FROM Subscriber WHERE Type= ....."
```

but it display nothing.

Can someone please guide me function?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using (I would guess MySQL).

Comment: not to mention the php tag (no code to support the question) and which API used to connect with, if this is to be used in a script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the max year and serial number, then use `right()` with `max()`:

```
SELECT max(right(serial, 6)),
FROM Subscriber
WHERE Type = . . .
```

If you want the entire `serial` or 16 characters, than use `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT serial
FROM Subscriber
WHERE Type = . . . 
ORDER BY right(serial, 6) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

(Both of these answers assume the database is MySQL, but other databases have the same functionality often expressed the same way.)

Comment: Sir, Thanks very much, This worked fine. I am creating function with the way you suggested. I would like to have your comments on function. kindly let me create and test it.